# Trying to use copy and swap idiom on operator=

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading, stdvector, copy-and-swap

While trying to implement MyVector I end up with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class MyVector
{
    int m_size = 0;
    int m_capacity = 0;

    T* m_data = nullptr;

public:
    MyVector()
    {
        cout << "defautl ctor" << endl;

        realloc(2);
    }

    MyVector(const MyVector& v)
    : m_size(v.m_size), 
      m_capacity(v.m_capacity)
    {
        cout << "copy ctor" << endl;

        m_data = new T[m_size];
        *m_data = *v.m_data;
    }

    MyVector(MyVector&& v)
    : m_size(v.m_size), 
      m_capacity(v.m_capacity)
    {
        cout << "move ctor" << endl;

        m_data = move(v.m_data);

        v.m_data = nullptr;
        v.m_size = 0;
        v.m_capacity = 0;
    }

    MyVector& operator= (const MyVector& v)
    {
        cout << "copy assignment operator" << endl;

        // m_size = v.m_size;
        // m_capacity = v.m_capacity;
        // *m_data = *v.m_data;

        MyVector<int> copy = v;
        swap(*this, copy);

        return *this;
    }

    void push_back(const T& value)
    {

        if (!(m_size < m_capacity))
        {
            // cout << value << " size is " << m_size << " capacity is " << m_capacity << endl;

            realloc(m_size*2);
            // return;
        }

        m_data[m_size++] = value;
    }

    T& operator[] (int index)
    {
        cout << "index " << index << " of size " << m_size << endl;

        if (!(index < m_size))
            cout << "index out of bounds" << endl;

        return m_data[index];
    }

    int size()
    {
        return m_size;
    }

    T* begin()
    {
        return &m_data[0];
    }

    T* end()
    {
        return &m_data[size()];
    }

private:
    void realloc(int new_capacity)
    {
        // cout << __func__ << " new capacity " << new_capacity << endl;

        T* data = new T[new_capacity];

        for (int i = 0; i < m_size; i++)
            data[i] = m_data[i];

        delete[] m_data;
        m_data = data;

        m_capacity = new_capacity;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cout << "starting..." << endl;

    MyVector<int> a;
    a.push_back(7);

    MyVector<int> d;
    d = a; 

    cout << a[0] << endl;
    cout << d[0] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Where the `operator=` is

```
    MyVector& operator= (const MyVector& v)
    {
        cout << "copy assignment operator" << endl;

        // m_size = v.m_size;
        // m_capacity = v.m_capacity;
        // *m_data = *v.m_data;

        MyVector<int> copy = v; // copy and swap
        swap(*this, copy);

        return *this;
    }
```

However this led to what seems to be a recursive behavior. So, is my understanding of the copy and swap approach wrong? Or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Where did you define your `swap` function for `MyVector`?

Comment: That's `std::swap`, isn't? Should I write my own swap?

Comment: FYI: `*m_data = *v.m_data;` -- That looks highly suspicious.  This does not do a copy of the data from one dynamic array to the other.  I would expect a call to `std::copy` with the appropriate arguments.

Comment: `std::swap` uses `MyVector::operator=`, thus the recursion. Is it surprising you?

Comment: If you don't write your own swap, you'll get the fallback `std::swap` which will do the `MyVector temp = a; a = b; b = a;`.  Which is recursive, given your `operator=`.

Comment: FYI: `MyVector& operator= (const MyVector& v)` could be: `MyVector& operator= (MyVector v)`.  With that, your code doesn't need to manually create the copy here `MyVector<int> copy = v; // copy and swap`, plus the compiler has a better chance of optimizing the code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the copy-and-swap idiom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom)

Comment: Note well that the answers to the dupe target explicitly discuss how you must write your own swap for copy & swap, not use `std::swap`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, appreciate if you could expand on that. If `code doesn't need to manually create the copy` what happens instead?

Comment: @KcFnMi -- Since the parameter would be passed by-value, the compiler will automatically make the copy.  Since the compiler will be making the copy, the compiler knows how to optimize the "copy making".  By you stepping in and manually creating the copy, you are potentially stopping the compiler from optimizing your code right there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in comments, you did not implement a `swap()` function for `MyVector`, so the statement `swap(*this, copy);` is calling `std::swap()` (one of the [many pitfalls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) of using `using namespace std;`), which will invoke your `operator=` again, hence the recursive behavior you are seeing.

Also, your copy constructor is not implemented correctly. It is not copying all of the elements from the input array into the new array.  It is copying only the 1st element.

Also, you are missing a destructor to free the allocated array.

Also, since `MyVector` has both copy and move constructors, your two assignment `operator=`'s can (and should) be merged into one operator that takes a `MyVector` by value.  This lets the compiler decide whether to call the operator with copy or move semantics depending on whether the caller is passing in an lvalue or an rvalue, respectively.  The operator can then just `swap` whatever it is given, as the input will have already been copied or moved before the operator is entered.

Try something more like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>

template <typename T>
class MyVector
{
    int m_size = 0;
    int m_capacity = 0;
    T* m_data = nullptr;

public:
    MyVector()
    {
        std::cout << "default ctor" << std::endl;

        realloc(2);
    }

    MyVector(const MyVector& v)
    {
        std::cout << "copy ctor" << std::endl;

        realloc(v.m_capacity);
        std::copy_n(v.m_data, v.m_size, m_data);
        m_size = v.m_size;
    }

    MyVector(MyVector&& v)
    {
        std::cout << "move ctor" << std::endl;

        v.swap(*this);
    }

    ~MyVector()
    {
        std::cout << "dtor" << std::endl;

        delete[] m_data;
    }

    MyVector& operator= (MyVector v)
    {
        std::cout << "assignment operator" << std::endl;

        v.swap(*this);

        return *this;
    }

    void push_back(const T& value)
    {
        if (m_size >= m_capacity)
        {
            // std::cout << value << " size is " << m_size << " capacity is " << m_capacity << std::endl;

            realloc(m_size * 2);
        }

        m_data[m_size] = value;
        ++m_size;
    }

    T& operator[] (int index)
    {
        std::cout << "index " << index << " of size " << m_size << std::endl;

        if (index < 0 || index >= m_size)
            throw std::out_of_range("index out of bounds");

        return m_data[index];
    }

    int size() const
    {
        return m_size;
    }

    T* begin()
    {
        return &m_data[0];
    }

    T* end()
    {
        return &m_data[m_size];
    }

    void swap(MyVector &other)
    {
        std::swap(m_data, other.m_data);
        std::swap(m_size, other.m_size);
        std::swap(m_capacity, other.m_capacity);
    }

private:
    void realloc(int new_capacity)
    {
        // std::cout << __func__ << " new capacity " << new_capacity << std::endl;

        T* data = new T[new_capacity];

        std::copy_n(m_data, m_size, data);
        std::swap(m_data, data);
        m_capacity = new_capacity;

        delete[] data;
    }
};

// for std::swap() to use via ADL...
void swap(MyVector &v1, MyVector &v2)
{
    v1.swap(v2);
}
```

Comment: Concerning the `operator=` merge, if I choose not to merge it then the alternative could be having `MyVector& operator= (const MyVecto&r v)` and `MyVector& operator= (MyVector&& v)` with same body?

Comment: @KcFnMi they would have similar code, but not exactly the same code, eg: `MyVector& operator= (const MyVector &v) { if (&v != this) { MyVector temp(v); temp.swap(*this); } return *this; } MyVector& operator= (MyVector &&v) { MyVector temp(std::move(v)); temp.swap(*this); return *this; }`